# Attempt to start Thread again or make a new one?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, boolean

I have a thread that acts as a timer, and counts seconds.

At some point, the `boolean` responsible for running the `while loop` is set false, and the thread ends up terminated.

In such cases, how could I set that thread up to start again? Should I assign the same variable a new thread or somehow attempt to call `thread.start();` again?

Comment: When threadRunning is set to false, your run() method exits.  How do you expect it to start again?

Comment: Hmm, won't "t1.start()" start/run it once again? This, however, didn't work.